On conflict do nothing returns created or previous record
Imagine that I have the following table:
CREATE TABLE users (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  name VARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

And the following Rust structs:
#[derive(Debug, Queryable, Selectable, Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::users)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct User {
    id: i32,
    created_at: SystemTime,
    updated_at: SystemTime,
    name: String,
}

#[derive(Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = crate::schema::users)]
#[diesel(check_for_backend(diesel::pg::Pg))]
pub struct NewUser {
    name: String
}

I want to be able to call a function that either create or get the user with the following name. So if the user does not exists it creates it, and if the user already exists it returns that record. For that I thought I could use the diesel method on_conflict_do_nothing() as follow:
pub fn create_or_get(&self, user_name: &String) -> QueryResult<User> {
        use self::schema::users::dsl::*;
        let new_user = NewUser::from(user_name.clone());
        let conn = &mut self.pool.get().unwrap();
        diesel::insert_into(users).values(&new_user).on_conflict_do_nothing().returning(User::as_returning()).get_result(conn)
    }

But I am getting Err.NotFound when the name is already in the database. Any idea what am I doing wrong?


Look at the Postgres log for the complete error message. 1) I'm betting it due to this On Conflict: The SET and WHERE clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to the row proposed for insertion using the special excluded table., which implies DO NOTHING does not have access to the proposed row.


The answers here How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL? indicate non-trivial solutions.

@AdrianKlaver the error I get is: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_name_key"


In psql do \d  users and add the output to your question text. 2) As of now it looks like it is tripping the UNIQUE constraint on name. I could not replicate with a simple case. The Postgres log should show you the complete text of the query that failed, if so add it to question text.


I should have added I am not using Rust, I'm working directly via psql.

ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING works as advertised: it does nothing if a row exists that conflicts with the declared unique constraint. So it also returns no row. All the gory details:

How to use RETURNING with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL?

Your case is actually more narrow - and thus simpler: SELECT or INSERT for a single input row, and you need to observe race conditions. I suggest a server-side PL/pgSQL function as laid out here:

Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?


OP, if you do use a server-side function, you can use it in Diesel via define_sql_function! with the appropriate DSL types.
